# my windows 7 and other patition disks not appear after installing ubuntu 14.10

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, hard-drive

While booting when I am press <kbd>shift</kbd> then options are shown, but window selection option is missing.

Also I am not able to download any software from Ubuntu Software Centre.

When I try to install, after some time it shows the message "failed to download repository information" and "check your internet connection"

When I do `sudo fdisk -l` I get this:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x03dc1158

Device     Boot  Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *      2048    499711    497664   243M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       501758 976771071 976269314 465.5G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       501760 976771071 976269312 465.5G 8e Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 461.7 GiB, 495695429632 bytes, 968155136 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 3.8 GiB, 4097835008 bytes, 8003584 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

I am trying to install GRUB in all partition drives, but they are not being shown.

Comment: There is no more Windows there. I suggest that you start again with the backup that you did when you followed the installation instructions for Ubuntu and then try again, this time saying to the installer NOT to use the whole disk (as you did, since you ended up with LVM)

Answer (score 0):

I've dealt with the same issue few days ago. You need windows installation usb/dvd. Boot and repair boot manager. Then update grub update from ubuntu live usb.